# Delete isolated cells in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cell

I could really use some advice on the following code I've written.
Basically I created a 2D array profile, with `active (1)` and `inactive (0)` cells. However, I get disconnected cells, which is a cell with a value 1 but surrounded by cells with value 0. However, I would like to turn this `active cell (1)` then to an `inactive cell (0)`. My script does run, the result is that an active cell stays active, despite being surrounded by inactive cells. I have written the following code down below:

```
 def find_lonely_cells(ibound_array):

    col_n = ibound_array.shape[-1]
    row_n = ibound_array.shape[0]

    #   go through the ibound_arr cell by cell
    for i in xrange(1, col_n-1, 1):
        for j in xrange(1, row_n-1, 1):
            cell_up = ibound_array[i,0,j-1]
            cell_down = ibound_array[i,0,j+1]
            cell_right = ibound_array[i+1,0,j]
            cell_left = ibound_array[i-1,0,j]

            if ibound_array[i,0,j] == 1:
                continue

            if i == 0:
                if j == 0:
                    if (cell_right == 0 and cell_down == 0):
                        ibound_array[i,0,j] = 0
                if (row_n -1) > j > 0:
                    if (cell_up == 0 and cell_right == 0 and cell_down == 0):
                        ibound_array[i,0,j] = 0

            elif i == (col_n - 1):
                if j == 0:
                    if (cell_left == 0 and cell_down == 0):
                        ibound_array[i,0,j] = 0
                if (row_n - 1) > j > 0:
                    if (cell_up == 0 and cell_left == 0 and cell_down == 0):
                        ibound_array[i,0,j] = 0

            elif j == 0:
                if i == 0:
                    if (cell_right == 0 and cell_down == 0):
                        ibound_array[i,0,j] = 0
                if (col_n -1) > i > 0:
                    if (cell_left == 0 and cell_right == 0 and cell_down == 0):
                        ibound_array[i,0,j] = 0

            elif j == (row_n - 1):
                if i == 0:
                    if (cell_up == 0 and cell_right == 0):
                        ibound_array[i,0,j] = 0
                if (col_n - 1) > i > 0:
                    if (cell_up == 0 and cell_left == 0 and cell_right == 0):
                        ibound_array[i,0,j] = 0
            else:
                if (col_n - 1) > i > 0 and (row_n-1) > j > 0:
                    if (cell_up == 0 and cell_right == 0 and cell_down == 0 and cell_left == 0):
                        ibound_array[i,0,j] = 0

        return ibound_array

ibound_arr = find_lonely_cells(ibound_array)
```

Just to clarify, because I have a 2D array, I have the value `0` for `[i,0,j]`, which stands for `0` rows.

The arrays size is quite large, as I am unable right now to change its size; `size: (120, 1, 150))`

```
[[[1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
[[1 1 1 ... 0 0 0]]
[[1 1 1 ... 0 0 0]]
...
[[0 0 0 ... 0 1 0]]
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]]
```

I hope despite this that my question is clear. If anyone sees any mistakes in my script, please let me know. I could use some advice on how to imporove this and make it work.

Thank you!

[Image of disconnected cells I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYpuj.png)

---

Minimal example of the input:

```
a = np.array([[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
              [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
              [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
              [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0],
              [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
              [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1]])
a = a.reshape(6,1,8)
```

Maybe a better example would be

```
h = np.array([[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
              [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
              [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
              [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0],
              [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1],
              [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1]])

#h = h.reshape(6,1,8)
```

Notice the `one` at h[3,6] has `zeroes` to the left, right, top and bottom but the *adjacent diagonals* are `one`.

Comment: What is the array's shape? Please post an example of the array - like `a=np.ndarray([[...],[...],...])` (using real values of course).

Comment: `This script didn't work...` is a bit vague, can you describe the problem better in (please don't answer in a comment, update the question).

Comment: When a cell is evaluated and it gets *deleted* it may cause a subsequent cell to become *disconnected* and *deleted*, even if originally it was NOT *disconnected*.  Is this behaviour desired?  In addition to an example input, please include the desired output.

Comment: `return ibound_array` is within the outer loop the function will return after the first iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Please don't refine the question in comments - update the question itself so everyone will understand without reading the comments. It is easier for us and you to test your code if we have an example input and the desired output - included in the question. It is also easier to test with minimal examples like an array with shape `(12, 1,15)`.  The easier you make it for *us* the more likely someone will spend the time to help. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.
[You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755).  I have added an example input to your question - if it does not represent the actual input (at reduced scale)  please edit it then add your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

We could start again, using a convolution:

```
import scipy.signal
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
              [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
              [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
              [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0],
              [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
              [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1]])
b = scipy.signal.convolve2d(a, np.ones((3,3)), 'same')
```

Here we have taken the convolution (ie found the number of co-occurrences) for each spot with a 3*3 array of 1s. The 'same' argument gives us no padding around the boundaries. Thus the number of neighbors is the b:

```
b
array([[1., 3., 4., 6., 6., 6., 6., 4.],
       [3., 6., 7., 9., 8., 7., 6., 4.],
       [4., 7., 8., 9., 7., 6., 4., 3.],
       [5., 7., 6., 7., 5., 4., 1., 1.],
       [4., 6., 4., 6., 5., 6., 4., 3.],
       [2., 3., 1., 3., 3., 4., 3., 2.]])
```

So, we can subset our a by the places where b == 1, and reassign:

```
a[b == 1] = 0
a

array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Using your multid array also works, change the function to `convolve`, and use np.ones((3,1,3)):

```
b = scipy.signal.convolve(a, np.ones((3,1,3)), 'same')
a[b == 1] = 0
```

Comment: `convolve2d` includes the *corner* cells of each *patch* in the evaluation.  The OP's code only evaluates the cells above, below left and right. Since the OP didn't provide a desired result it isn't clear what they wanted.

Comment: in that case, simply change the np.ones(3,3) to the desired mask: `np.array([[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]])`

Answer (score 0):

```
ibound_array[i,0,j] == 0
```

should be

```
ibound_array[i,0,j] = 0
```

And move the return statement out of the loops.

Edit:
You should also change your for loops to

```
for i in xrange(1, col_n-1, 1):
for j in xrange(1, row_n-1, 1):
```

otherwise your will get out of bound errors.
You can also check if the cell is actually 1:

```
if ibound_array[i,0,j] == 0:
    continue
```

Edit2:
There are also mistakes in your conditions:

```
(row_n -1) < j > 0:
(col_n -1) < i > 0:
```

should be

```
(row_n -1) > j > 0:
(col_n -1) > i > 0:
```

Comment: Ah that's a really good point! I fixed this, but unfortunately it still didn't give me the result I was hoping for. The 'disconnected' cells are still active..

Comment: Thank you, I updated it with your suggestions. Don't you mean however 
if ibound_array[i,0,j] == 1 ? Or am I mistaken here? 

I still don't get the correct result though. Are there any more mistakes I did not see?

Comment: No, you only want to check cells containing a 1, and 
if ibound_array[i,0,j] == 0: 
     continue  
ignores cells containing a 0.